# access PyQt component from other class

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

i have a PyQt Class, and i want to change label text from other class. but i got this error

> AttributeError: 'GUI_animate' object has no attribute 'label_2'

this is label 2 definition in PyQt class :

```
self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox_4)
self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 60, 20))
self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
```

in the other class, i created instance from the pyQt class, and use this instance to access label2, but i got the previous error.

```
aa = GUI_animate()
self.aa.label_2.setText('Text Changed')
```

can anyone help ?

Comment: You have `aa =` and then `self.aa` - could it be simply that the first line should have been `self.aa = ` ?

Comment: Based on the error, my guess is that your actual code has `self.aa = GUI_animate()`. Does the line `self.label_2 = ...` appear in `GUI_animate.__init__()`?

Answer (score 0):

QLabel() is from QtWidgets... so it's QtWidgets.QLabel()

Text change must not have self.

Hope this helps.

```
import sys
# from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class GUI_animate(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        # self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 60, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("First text")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.label_2 )
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    aa = GUI_animate()
    aa.label_2.setText('Text Changed')
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```